# When I click on Forgot password app crash

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, crash

This is the code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var txtForgotPassword: TextView
    lateinit var register: TextView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        txtForgotPassword = findViewById(R.id.frgtpass)
        txtForgotPassword.setOnClickListener {
  val intent=Intent(this@MainActivity,Register::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I faced:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vishesh.foodrunner/com.vishesh.foodrunner.Register}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see from the logs you have a property in MainActivity line 17 which you assigned `lateinit` property but forgot to initialize it. I am not sure if you used it or not but give a base value to it and the error will go away you can always change as it is a `var` variable.